# Отправка формы с вложением через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Пытаюсь сделать форму отправки отзыва с прикреплением фото пользователя который оставляет комментарий. Проблема в следующем: когда форма заполнена полностью, все хорошо, форма отправляется. Запись о новом комментарии добавляется. Но если не выбрать файл происходит ошибка. Подскажите как можно реализовать, чтобы форма отправлялась корректно, независимо от того добавил ли пользователь файл или нет.

Файл add_review.js

```
jQuery("#add_review").submit(function (e) {
    jQuery('#add_review_btn').attr("disabled", true);
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-content/themes/kidko-child/includes/add_review.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: () => {
            jQuery(this).trigger("reset");
            jQuery('#add_review_btn').removeAttr("disabled");
            jQuery('.error_message_div').html("Отправлено");
            
        },
        error: () => {
            
            jQuery('.error_message_div').html("Ошибка");
        jQuery(this).trigger("reset");
        jQuery('#add_review_btn').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Файл add_review.php{

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wp-load.php");
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/image.php");
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/file.php");
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/media.php");

$image_input_name = 'review_image';
$allowed_image_types = array('image/jpeg','image/png', 'image/webp');
$max_image_size = 1000 * 1000; 

$user_name    = trim($_POST["name"]);
$user_message = trim($_POST["message"]);
$user_rating  = trim($_POST["rating"]);

$post_data = array(
    "post_author"   => 1,
    "post_status"   => "publish",               # статус - «На утверждении»
    "post_type"     => "reviews",               # тип записи - «Отзывы»
    "post_title"    => "Отзыв - " . $user_name, # заголовок отзыва
    "post_content"  => $user_message,           # текст отзыва

);


function upload_user_file( $file = array() ) {
      $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );
      if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
          return false;
      } else {
          $filename = $file_return['file'];
          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );
          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
          wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
          if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
                return $attachment_id;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
if( empty( $_FILES )){
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, "rejting", $user_rating);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, "user_name", $user_name);

}

if( !empty( $_FILES )){
    if(isset($_FILES[$image_input_name]['size']) && $_FILES[$image_input_name]['size'] > 0){
        if(in_array($_FILES[$image_input_name]['type'], $allowed_image_types) && $_FILES[$image_input_name]['size'] <= $max_image_size){

    foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {
        if( is_array( $file ) ) {
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, "rejting", $user_rating);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, "user_name", $user_name);
        $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, "avatar", $attachment_id);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "происходит ошибка" Текст-то есть у ошибки?

Comment: да. "Requested JSON parse failed"